# ARMA fitting in R and SPSS

Tags: r, time-series, spss, arima

I do not know if this question has been answered but I couldn't find anything similar.
I am fitting an ARMA (1,1) on my log returns in R and I decided to use both R and SPSS to check my results. In R I used the following function and got this results

> arima(x = data$Log_Change, order = c(0, 0, 1))
>
> Coefficients:
>            ma1  intercept
>         0.0410    -0.0064 s.e.  0.0198     0.0056

I then tried using SPSS but the estimate of the MA1 is the negative of the ARIMA in R

```
    ARIMA Model Parameters                              
                Estimate    SE  t   Sig.
Constant        -.006   .006    -1.138  .255
MA  Lag 1   -.041   .020    -2.093  .036
```

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong.